# PowerBI Administration: Group (Workspace) Access

Tags: powershell, powerbi, office365

I need to get access to an existing PowerBI group on our online PowerBI instance.  Unfortunately the group creator / owner is not currently available.

I have the 'PowerBI Admin Role' - however when i try an access the group I get the error below:
[image]

I can see the group that I am trying to access from the PowerBI admin portal:

[image]

I have tried the PowerShell commandlet: Add-PowerBIWorkspaceUser

```
Add-PowerBIWorkspaceUser -UserPrincipalName myusername@tenancy.com -Id 12345678-ABCD-1234-ABCD-1234567890AB -AccessRight Member
```

This fails with an unauthorized response.  I assume this is because commandlet is for workspaces and not groups.

Is there a way for an admin user to amend the membership of a group they are not already a member of?

Comment: If the Workspace has created a Outlook/SharePoint/Teams group, can you add yourself to that?

Comment: @Jonee - that worked perfectly and in hindsight was the first thing i should have checked.  In fact the Group ID on the PowerBI url is Azure AD object ID for a group.  Just added to the group in Azure AD.  Thanks